# Issue while inspecting hybrid app. Not able to find required selectors

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, appium-desktop

I am automating a hybrid app using Appium, using real mobile device. So my code is written as below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

//capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "77377f50");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview", "true");

capabilities.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.englishbolo.android.alpha");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.englishbolo.android.ui.EnglishBoloSplashScreen filter 36b63470");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET,false);

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Set <String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();

for (String contextName : contextNames) 
{
    System.out.println("Available Context:"+contextName); 

}

driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@resource-id,'en_US')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'OK')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@text='SIGNUP FREE']")).click();

driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.Spinner").click();

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'userFullName')]").sendKeys("ebuat");

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@text='Sri Lanka+94']").click();

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'userPhone')]").sendKeys("744693540");

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'userPassword')]").sendKeys("1234");

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'userMailId')]").sendKeys("ebuatuser_nov18@sharklasers.com");

driver.hideKeyboard();

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='SUBMIT']").click();

driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='START NOW']").click();
```

After this last click action i need to click on radio buttons but after inspecting in appium desktop, only class as a locator is present.

For all radio button class `android.view.View` is the locator present.

I have used xpath using class name, text * resource-id present. If only classname is present So how can I form xpath to click on radio buttons?

```
Set <String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) 
{
    System.out.println("Available Context:"+contextName); 

}
driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]);
```

Also I have written method `getContextHandles` to set view to WebView.

**Error observed after writing this method:**

```
INFO: HTTP Status: '400' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: No such context found.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'englishhelper-MS-7A15', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-52-generic', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: NoSuchContextError: No such context found.
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.setContext (/tmp/.mount_AppiumZrt5AD/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/context.js:57:11)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'englishhelper-MS-7A15', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-52-generic', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
    at appium_new.AppiumSignup.main(AppiumSignup.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No such context found.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'englishhelper-MS-7A15', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-52-generic', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: NoSuchContextError: No such context found.
    at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.setContext (/tmp/.mount_AppiumZrt5AD/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/context.js:57:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 18 more
```

Can you please help me with the solutions you may know.

Comment: try following //*[@class = 'android.view.View']

Comment: Thank You @Deepak for your reply.  But I'm using a app which is rendred just by pointing it towards website. And website code is written in HTML / CSS format. For every radio button id is passed in the code, so the question is in my case app is just a copy of website, then why the id's are not visible when i inspect the app in appium desktop application. Please help me with this.

Comment: You need to share the HTML with the community, then only we can help. Without looking into it is tough for anybody.

Comment: Okay I'm sharing below html. This html exist when my website is inspected <input id="6898_20819" lang="userSelectedOption_1" type="radio" class="radio en_US" name="6898">.  But I wanted to ask the id which is shown here doesn't get inspect in appium desktop. So while running automation I'm not able to use id.  Because app which i'm using points to the same website.

Comment: It is not necessary that you would see 'Id' as locator in HTML. It means developers didn't prodided 'Id' for an element/object. So the only option left is either you ask developer to add  a unique 'Id' to the source code or you create XPath to locate the elements. Moreover, the HTML code provided by you is an insufficient information to provide any solution.